# Why does my go code hang whilst using goroutine and channels?

Tags: go

So I am wanting to make mutiple http request to an api endpoint I need to do give or take 15 thousand now I am wanting to make these requests as fast as possible but whilst also not running into any os issue as when I run it with just creating a new goroutine for each request I run into the socket:too many files open error. So after some research I came up with using a buffered channel to stack jobs that need to be ran and below is the code I got.

My issue is that it adds the 1000 jobs to be ran to the channel but does not actually run them it just hangs and does nothing until I terminate the program. Why is this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    jobsChannel := make(chan string, 1000)
    workers := 10
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    usernameAsPointer := getCommandArgs()
    username := *usernameAsPointer

    usernameID := getID(username)
    listOfAccounts := readFile()
    fmt.Printf("Loaded %d accounts!\n", len(listOfAccounts))

    // Fill up our jobs channel
    for _, account := range listOfAccounts {
        fmt.Println("Adding Jobs to the channel")
        fmt.Println(account)
        wg.Add(1)
        jobsChannel <- account
    }

    // Create a worker pool so we dont just kill the system we're running this on
    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        fmt.Println("We're running our jobs.")
        go func() {
            for accountInfo := range jobsChannel {
                followUser(usernameID, accountInfo)
                wg.Done()
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the program stuffs the channel before the workers start, the program will hang when `len(listOfAccounts)` is greater than `cap(jobsChannel)`.  Fix by starting the workers first.

Another issue is that the worker goroutines will hang forever receiving on `jobsChannel`.  Close the channel to allow those goroutines to complete.

Use the wait group to wait for goroutines, not jobs.

With these changes, any capacity works for `jobsChannel`.  Some style guides recommend using capacity 0 or 1 unless there's a specific reason to use a larger capacity. There's not a reason to use a capacity of 1000, so I switched the capacity to 1.

Here's the updated code with additional commentary.

```
jobsChannel := make(chan string, 1)
workers := 10
var wg sync.WaitGroup

usernameAsPointer := getCommandArgs()
username := *usernameAsPointer

usernameID := getID(username)
listOfAccounts := readFile()

// Create the worker goroutines. Increment wait group when
// creating a worker and decrement when the worker exits.
for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for accountInfo := range jobsChannel {
            followUser(usernameID, accountInfo)
        }
    }()
}

// Send jobs to the workers.
for _, account := range listOfAccounts {
    fmt.Println("Adding Jobs to the channel")
    fmt.Println(account)
    jobsChannel <- account
}

// Close channel to signal workers that no more jobs are coming.
// The workers break out of the for range loops when the channel is
// closed.
close(jobsChannel)

// Wait for workers to complete.
wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using channels and WaitGroups is fragile. Channels should not need to completely buffer their contents; you don't know how large listOfAccounts is and if it's larger than the buffer you'll deadlock. WaitGroups are generally for goroutines, not data in channels.

Instead, [indicate you're done adding to the channel by closing it](https://gobyexample.com/closing-channels). Closing a channel does not delete what's already in the channel. It just lets readers know to not wait around for more data from that channel.

Now you can feed jobsChannel in a goroutine while also processing it. This avoids having to buffer everything and your workers and feeders can be set up in any order you like.

```
    workers := 10
    jobs := 1000
    // You don't need a buffer, but a small one doesn't hurt.
    jobsChannel := make(chan int, workers*2)

    go func() {
        defer close(jobsChannel);
        for account := 0; account < jobs; account++ {
            jobsChannel <- account
        }
    }();
```

Then use WaitGroups to wait until all the goroutines finish. Each goroutine will finish when the channel is closed and there's no more data in the channel buffer.

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup;
    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for account := range jobsChannel {
                fmt.Println(account)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
```